# Deploy Laravel and Angular project on client system without using localhost or Command

Tags: mysql, angular, laravel, deployment, local

I created a project using Angular and Laravel and want to run it on user system without using localhost and "php artisan serve" command because user doesn't know all these command and doesn't go to technicality. I created the desktop app of my Front End code by using Electron and want to communicate with Laravel app without using any localhost server.

I already deployed this project using XAMPP but after some days when data increased then XAMPP faced issues and didn't response so i didn't want to use localhost for future.

I simply want solution through with i run this project on user system without running localhost or some kind of command. I simply want to communicate with Laravel app from my Front end Angular code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Docker + docker-compose.
It's easy to setup environment for project and if you want you can run it in a background mode on "user" side.

Comment: So it is compulsory to also install Docker on user side.

Comment: Of course, you should install environment once on user side. I can't catch an idea of question. How you imagine is it possible to setup Laravel etc. without any environment? In case with Docker it's easy to perform virtualization so easy to setup on user side as well.